# Understanding the Pascal equivalent to C/C++ forward declaration of types

Tags: pascal, freepascal, forward-declaration

I know forward declarations from C/C++, and I know why and how they are used. When changing to Pascal, I'm missing a true equivalent of this feature. If I try to declare a type that I'm using (via pointer) in another type, like so,

```
type
  TBRec = record
    FA: ^TARec;
  end;

  TARec = record
    FB: ^TBRec;
  end;
```

Pascal (in fact, I tried with Free Pascal) implicitly deduces incomplete types from the `^` preceding an identifier (that is treated as an incomplete type). But this technique is limited to the scope of **the same type definition section**.

Is it possible to place related type definitions into separate units, and how to do this?

---

Edit: I falsely wrote `class` for `TARec`, it should be `record` in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

The Pascalish way to do such things is:

```
type
  // Forward declarations of pointers
  PARec = ^TARec;
  PBRec = ^TBRec;

  TBRec = record
    FA: PARec;
  end;

  TARec = record
    FB: PBRec;
  end;
```

[Read more here](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/fpcdoc/ref/refse16.html#x43-490003.5)

It works in case if all declarations are in the same unit and same `type` section.

In case if declarations are splitted in different units it can be solved using untyped pointers, explicit types casting and cyclic units references:

```
unit a;

interface

  PARec = ^TARec;
  TARec = record
    FB: Pointer; // Untyped pointer
  end;  

implementation

uses
  b; // Cyclic unit reference in the implementation section, see unit b below

procedure foo;
var
  ra: PARec;
begin
  ra := New(PARec);
  ra^.FB := New(PBRec);
  PBRec(ra^.FB)^... // PBRec is declared in the b unit
  // or
  TBRec(ra^.FB^)...
end;

end.
```

---

```
unit b;

interface

uses
  a;

type
  PBRec = ^TBRec;
  TBRec = record
    FA: PARec; // We can use PARec type because it already known here
  end;
```

Comment: This seems not to be true for the recent Free Pascal version, this compiles without complains: `type
  TForward = record
    FF: ^TForward;
    i: Integer;
  end;`

Comment: @Wolf Question not to me but to FPC team :) However it is the common practice which you can meet frequently in the pascal code.

Comment: But, to get back to the original question, what can be done if one wishes to place the type definitions into the interfaces of different units? Impossible?

Comment: Is this the **only** or **the common** way: to break up type safety for one of the pointers? Maybe this could be made a little bit more explicit. (+1d anyway)

Comment: @Wolf If you want to have **cyclic** references between **record** types and you want to keep them in the **different** units - yes.However you can 1) use include files instead of units 2) use classes and interfaces instead of records 3) use record helpers. It depends on your task.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a forward declaration by define an empty class or interface. You are able to specify the type later **in the same type declaration section** but you can already use it between the forwarded and the specified declaration.

```
type
  TARec = class; // <-- Forward declaration

  TBRec = record
    FA: ^TARec;
  end;

  TARec = class
  public
    FB: ^TBRec;
  end;
```

So it is not possible to declare a forwarded type in file A.Pas and specify it in file B.pas

Comment: But this is also restricted to the same type definition section, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is bound to the same type declaration section. I edited the answer.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't help; as I mentioned in the question, `^TARec` already implicitly does the forward declaration, so no explicit forward declaration is needed. BTW: `class` <> `record`. You probably tried the same as I when I discovered the effect of `^` :-)

Comment: @Wolf Also keep in mind that a class variable is already a pointer in ObjectPascal. I just don't know what the meaning of declaration like `FA: ^TARec;` because I never used something like that. For class types do not use `^` modifier.

Comment: @Wosi *`is not possible to declare a forwarded type in file A.Pas and specify it in file B.pas`* -- well, it seems so. Do you have an reference (link) at hand?

Comment: @Wosi sorry, I **wished** I've used only records in my question, but now I see that I mixed that up. I corrected it, again sorry!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a link. As far as I know there is no official language specification for FreePascal.

Comment: @Abelisto Thanks for pointing me on that. I mistakenly used `class` instead of `record`, sorry for the confusion. (I'm aware of the class variables being pointers in Free/Object Pascal)

Comment: Wosi: there is a reference guide that is semi formal. If you miss something please file a bug